# Adjusting position on discrete x-axis of two goups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with a continous y-axis and discrete x-axis. 
For the data I have a group factor with 3 levels and 2 meausement points, so 6 geoms are created
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/259IT.jpg)
I would like to keep the width of the single geoms but adding space between the two measurement points, respectively the two groups of geoms. Like: 3 geoms - gap - 3 geoms. Is there any possibility of adjusting the position of a group of geoms on the x-axis in ggplot?

```
preferences %>%
  pivot_longer(c(F1_life_satisfaction_pre, F1_life_satisfaction_current), names_to = "variables", values_to = "ratings")%>%
    ggplot(  aes(y=ratings, x=fct_inorder(variables), fill=fct_inorder(playing_preference))) + 
    geom_violin(scale="width", adjust=0.5, width=0.8, alpha= 0.2, position = position_dodge(1)) +
    stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, position = position_dodge(1)) +
    stat_summary(aes(group=fct_inorder(playing_preference)), fun=mean, geom = "line", size= 0.5, position = position_dodge(1)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(mult=1),aes(x=fct_inorder(variables), y=ratings), geom="errorbar", 
                 width=0.05, position = position_dodge(1)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("pre-Pokemon-Go", "current"),expand = c(0, 0.3)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size=10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), limits=c(1,7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y=4, yend=4, xend=3), color="grey") +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
    labs(fill = "playing preference") +
    labs(x="life satisfaction") +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10))+
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
    labs(y = "mean ratings") +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1,color="black", alpha=0.2, position = position_dodge(1)) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete=T)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, share with us the code you used to generate that graph with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR - play with `width=` and `position_dodge(width=...)` within your line for `geom_violin` and `geom_boxplot` to adjust the positions along with `scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(...)`.

The first point is that the resolution (and how close and far apart) things are on your plot will be related to the size of your window.  With that being said, the positioning relationship of the plot elements between one another can be controlled via `ggplot`.  In particular, you want to change the values of `width=` and `position_dodge(width=...)` in your `geom_violin` call (and your `geom_boxplot` call).

#### Example Dataset

I'll use an example dataset to illustrate the idea, where I'll plot boxplots... but the idea is identical.  The example dataset contains two x values ("Group1" and "Group2"), and each of those has subdivisions that are either "A", "B", or "C", containing a separate normal distribution of 50 datapoints for every `x` and `x.subdiv`.

```
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
  x=c(rep('Group1', 150), rep('Group2', 150)),
  x.subdiv=rep(c(rep('A', 50), rep('B',50), rep('C',50)), 2),
  y=unlist(lapply(1:6, function(x){rnorm(50, runif(1,10,15), runif(1,0,7))}))
)
```

#### Width of position_dodge

Here's the simple boxplot, where I'll use `0.5` as the value for both `width=` and `position_dodge(width=...)`.  *Note that the first argument in `position_dodge` is `width=`, so you can just supply that number directly to that function without explicitly assigning to the `width` argument.*

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme_bw()
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image]

The rule to note here is:

- `geom_boxplot(width=...)` controls how wide the overall spread of box plots are around each `x=` value.
- `position_dodge(width=...)` controls the amount of spread (the amount of "dodging") for the groups around the `x=` aesthetic.

So this is what happens when you change `position_dodge(width=1)`, but leave `geom_boxplot(width=0.5)`:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(1))
```

[image]

The width of each box remains the same as before, but the positioning of each box around `x=` is more "spread out".  In effect, each is "dodged" more.  If you set `position_dodge(width=0.2)`, you'll see the opposite effect, where the boxes become squished together (because they are not spread out as much around `x=`):

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.2))
```

[image]

The interesting thing is how `geom_boxplot(width=)` and `position_dodge(width=)` are related:

- If `geom_boxplot(width=)` is equal to `position_dodge(width=)`, the boxes will be touching
- If `geom_boxplot(width=)` is less than `position_dodge(width=)`, the boxes will be separated from one another
- If `geom_boxplot(width=)` is greater than `position_dodge(width=)`, the boxes will be overlapping one another

#### Width of the geom

The `width=` of the geom itself relates to how wide the boxplots are.  The point to keep in mind are these two points:

1. The `width=` is the sum of all the widths of the individual dodged geoms for that particular `x=` aesthetic.
2. `width=1` is the width between two values on a discrete axis, meaning when you set `width=1`, the boxes will be wide enough to touch

That means that if we set `geom_boxplot(width=1)`, the combined total of all the boxes for "Group1" will be wide enough to touch the boxes of "Group2"... but you would only see that if there were no overlap among the boxes (meaning that `position_dodge(width=)` would be equal to `geom_boxplot(width=)`).

So this makes the boxes *wide enough* to be touching, but `position_dodge(width)` is less than `geom_boxplot(width)`... so the boxes overlap, but "Group1" boxes are separated from "Group2" boxes:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=1, position=position_dodge(0.8))
```

[image]

If we want everything to touch, you have to set them equal, and both equal to 1:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=1, position=position_dodge(1))
```

[image]

#### Control both widths

In the end, it's probably best to control both.  If we go from the previous plot, you probably want the plots to have separation between "Group1" and "Group2".  That means you need to make the width of all boxes smaller (which we control by `geom_boxplot(width)`).  However, you probably still want the dodging to leave a bit of space between the boxes, so we'll have to set `position_dodge(width)` to be greater than `geom_boxplot(width)`, but not too large so that we lose the separation between "Group1" and "Group2".  Something like this works pretty well:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.55))
```

[image]

In your case, you have both `geom_violin` and `geom_boxplot`, so you'll need to adjust those together and work out the proper look.

#### EDIT: "Shift Left and Right" and "Squish"

If the `width=` and `position_dodge(width=` arguments are just not quite getting you what you need, there is another parameter that can work in concert with them to move things around.  This would be to use `scale_x_discrete(expand=...` to control the amount of space to the left and right of your x axis items.  Used together with `width=` and `position_dodge(width=`, this actually gives you precise control of where to position your data along the x axis while still respecting the automated plotting that `ggplot2` provides.

- `width=` controls the whitespace between data along the x axis
- `position_dodge(width=` controls the amount of whitespace between subgroups in the data positioned along the x axis
- `scale_x_discrete(expand=...` controls white space to the left and right sides of the panel.

I'll demonstrate the functionality using the same dataset as before.  Note that proper use of the `expand=` argument for `scale_x_discrete` should call `expansion()` and you will need to provide a 1 or 2 length vector to either `add=` or `mult=`.  Play around with both and numbers to see the effect, but here's kind of what to expect.

The `expansion()` function takes either `mult=` or `add=` as arguments, which can either be a vector of length 2 (where [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVOHA.png) is applied to left side and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Gw5.png) is applied to the right side, or length 1 (where the number is applied to both sides).  Numbers sent to `mult=` are multiplied by the normal expansion to give you the new amount, so the code below sets the extra whitespace to the left and the right equal to 30% (0.3 * normal) of the typical expansion for *both sides*:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.55)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(mult=0.3))
```

[image]

Sending two values, you can adjust separately.  This sets the left side to be 100% (normal) and the right side to be reduced to 50% of normal:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x.subdiv), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.55)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(mult=c(1,0.5)))
```

[image]

**Bottom Line:** Seems like by using all three arguments for `width=`, `position_dodge(width=`, and `scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(...`, you can theoretically place your x groupings anywhere along your plot.  Just keep in mind that the resolution and aspect ratio of your graphics device will change how things are laid out a bit, so additional control can be adjusted by resizing the graphics window.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

I have already adjusted geom_violin and geom_boxplot and the attached graphic was the optimum I could achieve.

Is there any possibility in ggplot to determine manually the positions of the geoms on the x-axis?

Comment: Not explicitly, but I've added a significant edit to the question that should allow for even more control by adjusting the whitespace to the right and left through `scale_x_discrete(expand...`

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this does not work. With expand i can only reproduce your second plot, not the first, but the first is exactly what I want. 
Do I have any command in the code which prevents that?

Comment: No, but fiddle with it, since your graphics device resolution can have an impact on what you see here.  In other words, `0.5` worked, but `0.3` did not?  Try a smaller number like `0.2` and see if that's where you see the change.  For me, if I went slightly higher on plot #1 in the value, I did not see much change vs. the original... but it did cause a change if I resized the window and compared them.  Sorry - hard to give clearer direction based on the nature of the output being based on your graphics resolution/size.

Comment: geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y=4, yend=4, xend=3) was the problem. If x-values are specified, the x limits of the plot change and scale_x_discrete(expand...) brings no change. Do you know if it is possible to draw a line along the entire length of the plot without specifying x values?